# How to fix the floating issue with Clearfix

Tags: html, css

I have built a square with CSS, but i am getting a Floating issue. I used clearfix approach but i guess i am making a small mistake in CSS.

```
body{
  margin: 0;
}
article:before {
  clear: left;
}
article {
    border: 2px solid #ccc;
  float: left;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;

}
```

Here is the [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xth03sqL/)

Comment: Clearfix is supposed to make the element go on a new line. And, in your example, it does. Maybe you should specify more clearly what is the desired behavior.

Comment: I am getting the output for square, but the article elements perhaps having floating issue in the body. If you inspect the body, you would understand that there is a floating issue

Comment: A note: I assume you got the _clearfix_ wrong. As a general clearing of floated children, it should be _after_, on the parent.

Answer (score 1):

You need `box-sizing:border-box` in the article rule. Example below:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

article:before {
  clear: left;
}

article {
  border: 2px solid #ccc;
  float: left;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

article:nth-of-type(1) {
  background-color: red;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 100px;
}

article:nth-of-type(2) {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 100px;
}

article:nth-of-type(3) {
  background-color: grey;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  clear: left;
  line-height: 100px;
}

article:nth-of-type(4) {
  background-color: green;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<article>1</article>
<article>2</article>
<article>3</article>
<article>4</article>
```

Comment: How do you know this is the expected behavior? Please refrain from making assumptions on the requirement. If the question, in its current form, is not specific enough to understand beyond reasonable doubt what is requested/asked, please use comments to ask for more details. Answering based on assumptions typically doesn't help OP and rarely helps future users.